# Visualization of the activations from CNN using Keras.Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, visualization

When I try to send an input to the network defined by the Keras.Model declaration I keep getting the same error whatever I do.

The prompt:

```
\> resource: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

is all get. I have tried to use `tf.disable_v2_behavior` to turn of the behaviour. I've also tried
`tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` and `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf` to no avail.

This is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
tf.disable_v2_behavior

# The dimensions of our input image
img_width = 100
img_height = 100
# Our target layer: we will visualize the filters from this layer.
layer_name = "block4_conv3"

# Set up a model that returns the activation values for our target layer
layer = model.get_layer(name=layer_name)
# creats 'limited' network to get output from specific layer.
feature_extractor = keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=layer.output)



def deprocess_image(img):
    # Normalize array: center on 0., ensure variance is 0.15
    img -= img.mean()
    img /= img.std() + 1e-5
    img *= 0.15

    # Center crop
    img = img[25:-25, 25:-25, :]

    # Clip to [0, 1]
    img += 0.5
    img = np.clip(img, 0, 1)

    # Convert to RGB array
    img *= 255
    img = np.clip(img, 0, 255).astype("uint8")
    return img


from IPython.display import Image, display
# We run gradient ascent for 30 steps
filter_index=0
iterations = 30
learning_rate = 10.0


# Expected input dimensions (1, 100, 100, 3)
# Generate noise as input 
img1 = tf.random.uniform((1, img_width, img_height, 3))
# Take input from data set 
img, label = display_generator.next()
#print(type(img))
#print(type(img1))

img=tf.convert_to_tensor(img)
#print(type(img))
#print(np.shape(img))


for iteration in range(iterations):
    #loss, img = gradient_ascent_step(img, filter_index, learning_rate)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(img)
        #loss = compute_loss(img, filter_index)
        #with tf.Session() as sess:
        #    activation=sess.run(feature_extractor(img))
        activation = feature_extractor(img)
        # We avoid border artifacts by only involving non-border pixels in the loss.
        filter_activation = activation[:, 2:-2, 2:-2, filter_index]    
        filter_activation=tf.reduce_mean(filter_activation)
        
    # Compute gradients.
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, img)
    # Normalize gradients.
    grads = tf.math.l2_normalize(grads)
    img += learning_rate * grads



# Decode the resulting input image
img = deprocess_image(img[0].numpy())

keras.utils.save_img("0.png", img)


display(Image("0.png"))
```

I have tried checking Tensorflow's site for a solution as well as a lot of third party websites for a solution but the only possible ways have either been to use 'tf.disable_v2_behavior', 'tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()', 'import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf' or:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
     activation=sess.run(feature_extractor(img))
```

None of which worked.

Any ideas?